# Error while calling spring boot api which is deployed in google App Engine through Cloud build

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, google-app-engine, spring-data-jpa, google-cloud-build

I am getting below response when calling any api of my spring boot application (Application is deployed in App Engine through Cloud Build)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title>500 Server Error</title>
    </head>
    <body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
        <h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
        <h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
            <p>Please try again in 30 seconds.
            </h2>
            <h2></h2>
        </body>
    </html>
```

when I check the logs it said **APPLICATION FAILED TO START** with below errors

> o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'jwtRequestFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.insta.invoice.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on InstaInvoiceApplication: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#cd1d761' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#cd1d761': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Throwables.throwIfUnchecked(java

> 2022-12-13 19:52:47.938 ERROR 11 --- [pool-1-thread-2] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CloudSqlInstance : Got more than one input failure. Logging failures after the first

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'long com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.exhaust(java.io.InputStream)' at com.google.api.client.http.ConsumingInputStream.close(ConsumingInputStream.java:40) ~[google-http-client-1.41.5.jar!/:1.41.5] at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.close(InflaterInputStream.java:231) ~[na:na] at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.close(GZIPInputStream.java:136) ~[na:na] at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.close(BufferedInputStream.java:481) ~[na:na] at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implClose(StreamDecoder.java:366) ~[na:na] at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.close(StreamDecoder.java:204) ~[na:na] at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.close(InputStreamReader.java:192) ~[na:na] at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.close(JsonReader.java:1229) ~[gson-2.9.1.jar!/:na] at com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonParser.close(GsonParser.java:51) ~[google-http-client-gson-1.41.5.jar!/:na] at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:363) ~[google-http-client-1.41.5.jar!/:1.41.5] at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:335) ~[google-http-client-1.41.5.jar!/:1.41.5] at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:79) ~[google-http-client-1.41.5.jar!/:1.41.5] at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:73) ~[google-http-client-1.41.5.jar!/:1.41.5] at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:461) ~[google-http-client-1.41.5.jar!/:1.41.5] at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565) ~[google-api-client-1.32.1.jar!/:1.32.1] at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CloudSqlInstance.fetchMetadata(CloudSqlInstance.java:462) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.5.0.jar!/:na] at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:108) ~[guava-19.0.jar!/:na] at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:41) ~[guava-19.0.jar!/:na] at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:77) ~[guava-19.0.jar!/:na] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na] at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

below is cloudbuild.yaml file

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: ['-c', 'gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1600 && gcloud app deploy']
timeout: '1600s'

options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.insta</groupId>
    <artifactId>filing</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>filing</name>
    <description>Invoice project </description>
<!--    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>-->

    <!-- The Spring Cloud GCP BOM will manage spring-cloud-gcp version numbers for you. -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.32.1</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Google Guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twilio.sdk/twilio -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
            <version>8.36.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>1</version>
                    <projectId>GCLOUD_CONFIG</projectId>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.2</version>
            </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.insta.invoice.InstaInvoiceApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties file

```
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name= connection-name
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=dbName
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password

# Configure connection pooling if needed
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10

spring.datasource.driver-class-name =org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

I am trying to get response from my api but Application is failed to start

Comment: Possibly setup issue, have you followed these steps from Google getting started instructions? like here https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-springboot#0 or others site that are also very good.

Comment: @mzm yes I am also guessing it is setup issue because same code was working in heroku but I am not able to understand the actual issue 

cloudbuild.yml file look like below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App is working fine credentials were not created for Cloud SQL Admin API. I have created the credentials and working fine.